# Choice of data structure for quicker search on values

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a set of values. As shown below, if I choose the value of 'A' then it should fetch the corresponding alias name.
In the example below, 'A' is mapped to corresponding value of 'UYT', so 'UYT' is the alias that needs to be fetched.

Here is the sample data:

```
RUB -->   F,D,E,R,T,Y,Y
WET -->   E,R,G,T,R,E,Q
UYT -->   Y,A,F,G,R,,T,U
```

Additionally, the search should follow the sequence of the search: First against the alias 'UYT', then 'WET' and so on.

Please advise which data structure would be best to maintain the above data, such that the data search would be fast.

I am considering using `HashMap` in which the key would be 'RUB', 'WET', 'UYT' and the corresponding set of values mapped to it would be the list of string values. However, I am not sure if this would give me the quickest search.

so for the values need to search the key

Comment: Do you want to search for `UYT` and find `A` or do you want to search for `A` and find `UYT`? Please, define your use case. Also, show us what have you tried and explain why do you think that hashmap won't be fast enough.

Comment: i need to search A to find UYT so in other words need to search key basis on values

Comment: In this keys why don't you store `A` as a key? You'll still need string to list of strings hashmap, but with slightly easier workflow.

Answer (score 0):

A [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would be sufficiently quick, and sounds like what you're describing. It will assign a numerical value to each key (RUB, WET, UYT) that is utilized in a function to retrieve the index value of the String from the table each time the value of a key is requested to be retrieved.

HashMap will be faster then HashTable because HashMap is unsynchronized.

Comment: HashMap will be better than HashTable.  (Link : http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/03/hashmap-vs-hashtable-difference-with-example-java-interview-questions.html)